Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Bitcoin Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Do bitcoin clients automatically add more fee than specified?

Net Score: 7 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Detecting generation transactions

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Will bitcoin's value be affected by other digital currencies?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to scan QR code with multibit wallet application?

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


What is the queue position?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)


Displayed transactions may not be correct!

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)


Can someone explain to me how do you read the blockchain.info transaction data?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to get a history of incoming and outgoing transactions for a certain address?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


where is default Bitcoin-Qt data directory?

Net Score: -5 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)


https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20086/what-companies-actively-sell-miners

Net Score: -6 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 7)

